# Problem while using NSSM to run a python program that calls julia code (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, service, julia, nssm

I am building an energy management system in python. To model the physical system I am using the [PandaPower library](https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which has the option to perform optimization using the Julia package PowerModels.jl. The program works as expected when executing it from the CMD, but I want to run it as a service so the OS makes sure it will be running all the time.

To run my program as a windows service I am trying using NSSM. The service starts and it shows as running, but for some reason it seems like it is unable to call the Julia code.

I have tried to find a clue by checking the loggs retrieved from the programm running on both the CMD and NSSM. The loggs generated from the programm running on the CMD look like this:

`2023-06-27 09:42:47,646:pandapower.opf.run_pandamodels:DEBUG:the json file for converted net is stored in: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pp_to_pm_v4qs_18d.json 2023-06-27 09:42:47,646:julia:DEBUG: 2023-06-27 09:42:47,646:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,646:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,658:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,690:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,955:julia:DEBUG:exception occured? None 2023-06-27 09:42:47,955:pandapower.opf.run_pandamodels:INFO:Optimization ('run_powermodels_opf') is finished in 0.16 seconds: 2023-06-27 09:42:47,971:pandapower.opf.run_pandamodels:DEBUG:the json file for converted net is deleted from C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pp_to_pm_v4qs_18d.json 2023-06-27 09:42:48,003:opcua.client.ua_client.Socket:INFO:opening connection`

While the logs generated from the programm running from NSSM look like this:

`2023-06-27 10:08:21,804:pandapower.opf.run_pandamodels:DEBUG:the json file for converted net is stored in: C:\Windows\TEMP\pp_to_pm_0ua7pq3q.json 2023-06-27 10:08:21,804:julia:DEBUG: 2023-06-27 10:08:21,820:opcua.client.ua_client.Socket:INFO:opening connection`

So it looks like the problem occours when calling the julia code using the julia package. The configuration of PowerMOdels.jl was done following these [steps](https://pandapower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/opf/pandamodels.html). Sadly, the only other piece of information I can get from the loggs is a "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" comming from the outputfile generated by NSSM, but that's it so I havent been able to figure what file it's missing and why.

As for the NSSM config I only set the path, the startup directory, and the configuration so It might be that I am missing something(?). I have tried checking on the Julia package code but i can't find anything suspocious; the problem must be arising from the NSSM.

I'd also appreatiate any approach different from NSSM that you can suggest to me. This is my first post so if I am missing some key info, I'd gratefull if you to let me know :)